# How to increment a TextView in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, try-catch, textview, android-progressbar

Everytime my `ProgressBar` reaches 100, I want the number in displayed in `textView2` to go up by one, and then the `ProgressBar` resets to 0, and it continues - 2, 3, 4 etc - so basically when the `ProgressBar` reaches 100, the level goes up by 1 which is displayed in `textView2`.
But, `textView2` only goes up to 1, then the `ProgressBar` obviously resets to 0, and the process continues, except the `textView2` does not display 2 or 3 etc.
My code at the moment makes `textView2` go from 0 to 1 when the `ProgressBar` reaches 100, and then the `ProgressBar` resets, but when it's full again, `textView2` does not change to 2.
So basically I want my `textView2` to increment every time the `ProgressBar` reaches 100.

```
if (levels.getProgress() == 100) {

                try {
                    double d = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(ph.getText()));
                    textView2.setText(String.valueOf( (int) d));
                    levels.setProgress(0);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter valid number.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `textView2` contains a **valid integer value** and you want that value increased by 1:

```
textView2.setText("" + (Integer.parseInt(textView2.getText().toString()) + 1));
```

Comment: `textView2` does contain an integer, but the app is crashing when the `ProgressBar` reaches 100. I pasted your code into my `if` statement and replaced my `try and catch` statement with your code

Comment: I just tried your edited code. It works, thank you so much!! :)